# Proper phonetic names and IPA symbols for Russian [i] in линия and English [i] in happy

Tags: ipa, phonemes

They have [i] on both [IPA:Russian wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/Russian) and [IPA:English wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/English)

On the Russian page the example is л**и**ния and on the English page it's happ**y**.
And in practice these are similar but clearly different sounds in these 2 examples, and in fact using the Russian variant of [i] is one of the most distinctive features of the Russian accent in English.

So the question is what are the proper names for these 2 different sounds and do they have different IPA symbols?

Comment: The fact that they use the same IPA symbol does not mean that they are the same sound when they’re from different languages. In narrow transcription, they’d probably be different. The /i/ that’s used for English isn’t even a single sound in itself: it’s the phoneme found in the word _happy_, which varies between [ə ~ ɨ ~ ɪ ~ i] according to dialect and speaker – pretty much every possible short English vowel from central to high front (plus [i], which doesn’t exist elsewhere at all).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you read the note number 35 under your link to the English pronunciation guide, there was: /i/ is the weak vowel in unstressed positions with range of the pronunciation from [ɪ] to [i], more close to [i].

On the other hand, in Russian there is the strong allophony
In different phonemic positions. And there is no phonemic length. So most distinguish features in the Russian accent are: a. /i/where [iː] or [ɪ] in stressed positions; b. /i/ instead of /iː/.
And about these effects of the allophony: prototypically, *happy* in the "russian" accent must be pronounced like /xʲæp(ː)ɨ/ because /Ci/ sequence in unstressed positions is [Cɨ].
But practically you must hear something like /xɛpːɨ̟ ~xɛ˧pːiː˧˥/.
It happens after the *хэппи* spelling.

Answer (score 1):

The standard IPA label for [i] is "close front unrounded vowel". The IPA operates in terms of a theory of universally-available phonemes, meaning that if [i] and [ɪ] contrast phonemically in some language, then there is a standard symbol for that difference. A symbol for a labiodental flap was added once it was proven that such a sound has phonemic status in some language. The actual phonetic value of [i] or [u], or any other sound, is a range. You can get some impression of that range by listening to the performances of four expert, on the [IPA performance page](https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/IPAcharts/inter_chart_2018/IPA_2018.html) (not that the 4 experts are not identical, they are close to each other).

The decision to write the Russian vowel as [i] is justified by the fact that no vowel is closer to that (judging from standard performances), at least from what I know of Russian. The decision to write the English vowel as [i] and not as [ɪ] is more ideological and not phonetically based, although it is also dialect-based. In many dialects, the vowel in "happy" really is [ɪ]. In most American dialects, it is somewhat diphthongal, so you could also write it as [ɪi] or something like that. There is also an analytic premise that English does not have word-final lax vowels, or even syllable-final lax vowels, so if you assume that, the vowel would have to be [i] and not [ɪ] (that is a big if, though).

There are a lot of diacritics that can be used to indicate raising and advancing or retraction and lowering, which could be pressed into service, but then one would have to decide whether Russian [i] is doubly-raised or just raised and English [i] is lowered, etc. That kind of micro-management of transcription is very misleading because it attempts to gain precision without using the tool that actually give you precision, namely acoustic analysis. Generally, phoneticians do not lard the data with diacritics, instead, they provide tables of formant values in controlled contexts.